# Custom-built desktop damaged by faulty PSU?

Tags: power-supply, post

I have a desktop with the following specs that's been working well for about a year now:

Gigabyte GA-H55M-S2H Mobo,
Corsair CX550M,
GTX 1060,
8 GB Corsair RAM,

... And PSU in it just died. I swapped it out for a brand new Thermaltake Smart 650W direct from the store. After starting it up, it doesn't display any video through the GPU and the GPU's fans spin extremely loudly for some reason. Taking out the video card and trying to use the onboard video doesn't work either. I'm at a loss, because I have isolated the system to just the RAM, Mobo, and CPU/Heatsink and tried another known working PSU just to be sure that the Thermaltake PSU wasn't DoA. I hear no beeps.

I've tried reseating all the components, and I have yet to identify a short. None of the capacitors on the board look damaged either. I have ensured that both the RAM and the GPU are good by testing them in another system.

Does anyone have any ideas what the dead PSU might have done to the machine, and where to go from here? Did the PSU take something with it, and if so, what?

Comment: Sounds like the MB's bad too, assuming you already tried resetting it (remove battery, reset jumper/button, etc)

Comment: Yes, I've tried both using the jumper and removing the battery and putting it back after about five minutes. Is there any chance it would be the processor? Don't have another machine to test it in.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's hard to test a cpu & motherboard without having another cpu & motherboard that work. I guess they don't fail in spectacular ways too often, with smoke & explosive residue, just seem to quit sometimes, or turn on & do nothing like yours (& a few of mine ;-)

Comment: Thanks much for your help. Ended up ordering a new motherboard and that did the trick.

Comment: That's good news that you've solved it... I suppose I might as well post my comments as an answer, then you could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the motherboard's bad too. If you've already tried resetting it (remove battery, reset jumper/button, etc) and it still doesn't work. The bad power could have damaged it, or possibly whatever damaged the power supply (power spike/brownout?) also damaged the motherboard.